# MVC - Fill DropDownList from 2 Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would Like to Know How I could Fill A DropDownList from 2 Tables. 
I have Tables:
Categories 
Subcategories

I should look like this:
-- Vehichles --  //From Categories
Cars             //From SubCategories
Bikes 
-- Houses --
Vila 
Aparatment

This tables are conected to eachother with foregin keys. and I use Linq to SQL.

Any Good Solution how to fill a dropdownlist from 2 tables?

Answer (score 2):

For display purposes, I'd recommend using the seldom used optiongroup tag.

For example:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This will group your sub categories together for easier display in the dropdown.